# Make ninja start from where it crashed

Tags: c#, c++, cefsharp, chromium-embedded, ninja

I was compiling CEF using ninja and it took 8 hours. There were 5 files left until it was done. The 5-th file was "libcef.dll" which I need for my project and I suspect that in one of the remaining 4 files there was "natives_blob.bin" which didn't generate and I need it. It crashed on the "libcef.dll" due to RAM being filled up. Is it possible to run ninja and make it start from where it crashed ? I really don't want my computer to be running at 100% CPU for another 8 hours and I don't want to wait another 8 hours because the whole CEF project took much more time to download and to fix all the issues with building/compiling. For those who might ask why am I building CEF, it's because I want proprietary codec support for my personal project which I can get when building CEF on my own.

Comment: Ninja was designed to build incrementally, so it should do that by itself. Of course we have no idea what build command you used or which wrappers are present.

Comment: Did you try? ninja shouldn't re-compile anything that hasn't been changed. This is default behavior.

Comment: @Botje If that's the case then I was pissed for no reason. I used "ninja -C out\Debug_GN_x86 cef". Just in case I am backing up everything (35GB of files) but as soon as I try it I will let you know. EDIT: Yes! It started from where it crashed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-running the ninja command is enough.